# Как добавить ignore файл в свой проект и какие папки он должен содержать?

Tags: java, git, github, gitignore

Моя последовательность действий
1) создал локальный гит репозиторий
2) скачал плагин ignore (и что за возня с этим игнором, в андроид студии например, автоматически он создается)
3) далее нажимаю по папке idea, вспомогательное меню, new - ignore - gitignorefile и что мне дальше выбрать?
4) выбирал template у меня сгенерировался какой файл, но сверху он предлагает создать .ignore файл
5) создал, перенес в него то что было в template созданном файле
6) если я правильно понял, у меня эти данные, что я внес должны стать бесцветными и когда я буду заливать проект на гитхаб, они не должны быть включены НО
7) они до того как я добавляю все unversion файлы в vcs в этом списке тоже есть
Что я делаю не так?
И еще вопрос, если у меня уже на гитхабе лежит папка с idea я могу как то это удалить без консольного способа